# Timer start time and end time calculation gives 4 secs extra

Tags: c#, silverlight, timer, windows-phone

i am working on WP8 , i am using timer where i am calulating the total time.

This is how i am doing it:

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
 timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);//interval for timer is 1 sec
 timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);//after the timer expires, this event is fired
 timer.Start();
 startDateTime = DateTime.Now;  

 DateTime et = DateTime.Now;

   Debug.WriteLine("st is "+startDateTime+ " et is "+et);

   TimeSpan myDateResult = et - startDateTime;
   double seconds = myDateResult.TotalSeconds;
   Debug.WriteLine("difference is " + seconds);
```

Output which i am getting :

```
st is 3/25/2014 3:54:09 PM et is 3/25/2014 3:55:14 PM
difference is 64.312636
```

So i run completely for 1 min then its giving me 64 sec as output. why so? is this a bug ?

**EDIT**

```
Here timerCount value is 60;

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                            
            timerCount--;
            if (timerCount > 0)
            {
                TimerText.Text = "Timer : "+timerCount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                TimerText.Text = "Timer : ";

            }            
        }
```

Comment: Please post the correct code, where is the `timer_Tick` implementation for example?

Answer (score 1):

So you are counting ticks with this timer and expecting after 60 ticks of 1s, exactly 1 minute will have passed.

It doesn't work like that. Other stuff is happening in the application, and .NET never assures it will be *exactly* one second between ticks.

If you want accuracy, use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` which gives a very accurate elapsed time based on the system clock.

Comment: Can you please give me some eaxmple or links that show me how to use it

Comment: Is Stopwatch supported in wp8?

Comment: It appears to be, confirmed via this link http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/alex_golesh/2012/11/05/whats-new-in-windows-phone-8-5-out-of-8quick-tip-creating-hybrid-applications/

Comment: Can you please help me to implement start time, interval and end time and remaining time calculations(like what i have shown in question) using stopwatch ?

Comment: If you are looking to have events raised with high precision (especially on WP) you are going to have an uphill struggle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212611/raise-event-in-high-resolution-interval-timer/4213950#4213950 for a detailed explaination - especially the second answer

Comment: Perhaps you could take a step back and explain what your scenario is, there may be an alternative approach we can recommend?

Comment: Ok, can you please invite me to a private chat room so that we can discuss on this,its very simple and i its talking very long time to fix this

Comment: as i am not able to create a chart room, i request you to please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool for calculating time. You should [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead of timer. Timer is used to do something that is meant to happen at a regular interval.

Comment: Is stop watch supported for WP8

Comment: in silverlight it does, not sure about WP8.

Comment: Can you please help me to implement start time, interval and end time and remaining time calculations(like what i have shown in question) using stopwatch ?

Comment: i have already posted the link that contains example. Why don't you follow that?

Comment: yes i have checked that but their i am not getting how to calculate the remaining time

Comment: StopWatch.Elapsed will give you the time that has elapsed.

Comment: What is happening is when i use this code and try to run the app , the app is not opening at all

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680751/longlistselector-with-list-item-selection-style